# Sqoop import not working in Hadoop 2.x

Tags: sqoop

I installed Hadoop-2.0.3 and Sqoop-1.4.4 and run Hadoop in pseudo distributed mode. When I try to import table from rdbms to hdfs issuing below command

```
master@hadoop:~/apps/sqoop-1.4.4$ bin/sqoop import  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoop  --username root --password root --table employees
```

I get the following error:

```
14/02/10 05:20:32 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
```

Can you please provide solution for this?

Comment: The comment on this jira ticket might help: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1151 and maybe this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-541

Comment: I'd ask this question at user@sqoop.apache.org. It seems like a configuration issue.